# flattening array of struct in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an XML file converted to dataframe using spark-xml package. The dataframe has the following structure:

```
root
 |-- results: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- result: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- categories: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- category: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

if I select the category column(which may appear multiple times under categories):

```
df.select((col('results.result.categories.category')).alias("result_categories"))
```

For one record, The result will look like

```
[[result1], [result2]]
```

I'm trying to flatten the results:

```
[result1, result2]
```

When I use the flatten function, I'm getting an error message:

```
df.select(flatten(col('results.result.categories.category')).alias("Hits_Category"))
 cannot resolve 'flatten(`results`.`result`.`categories`.`category`)' due to data type mismatch: The argument should be an array of arrays, but '`results`.`result`.`categories`.`category`' is of array<struct<value:string>
```

I end up creating a udf, and pass the column to the udf which spits out a flattened string version of the column.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7):

You're trying to apply [`flatten`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#flatten) function for an array of structs while it expects an array of arrays:

> `flatten(arrayOfArrays)` - Transforms an array of arrays into a single array.

You don't need UDF, you can simply [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) the array elements from struct to array then use `flatten`.

Something like this:

```
df.select(col('results.result.categories.category').alias("result_categories"))\
  .withColumn("result_categories", expr("transform(result_categories, x -> array(x.*))"))\
  .select(flatten(col("result_categories")).alias("Hits_Category"))\
  .show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.selectExpr("explode(results.result.categories.category) AS structCol").select(F.expr("concat_ws(',', structCol.*)").alias("single_col")).show()
```

Then the struct will be as string in one column and comma seperated.

Comment: What is F.expr?

Comment: @JimMacaulay https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.expr.html